# Code documentation in QTP / UFT

Tags: documentation, qtp, code-documentation

I am looking into ways of documenting my code in a JavaDocs kinda way.

Any ideas?

I use UFT 11.52

So far I have seen NaturalDocs + Perl.

Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In an optimal world, there would be a Javadoc-style document generator that uses the same "tags" as the function generator. I'm sure there is one, but I haven't met it yet, and could resist writing one for years. +1.

Answer (score 3):

At least one solution looks

- **practical**,
- **mature**,
- is **delivered in source code form** (consists of one huge (but very **professionally written**) VBS script that generates the documentation fragments),
- and is **absolutely free**:

> VBSdoc, "A VBScript API Documentation Generator"

See http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/vbsdoc.shtml.

The author appears to be very competent, given his high SO rep (see https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers), and the general quality of his website's content.

Of course, this one is built for standalone VBS scripts, not QTP/UFT scripts. But this should be no obstacle, given the source code is available.

I'd *love* to hear from you about experiences with this one. Feel free to edit them into this answer, be it accepted or not.

Comment: excellent find TheBlastOne. be sure that when (and if) I try it I will report back.

Answer (score 1):

I had success using Natural Docs several years ago.  It's one of the few things I blogged about: [automated code documentation for QTP](http://testtastic.blogspot.co.uk/2007/03/automated-code-documentation-for-qtp_08.html)

Comment: that is the only thing i kinda tried for now as i mentioned in my question. my problem is that editing all scripts having to open and check out from QC is a bit cumbersome to say the least. i was just wondering if there is something else out there .thanks GlennH!

Comment: You could create an OTA script to check out all tests at once. Or, to check them out and update them all at once programmatically. I personally have developed a script to sync a local filesystem tree with a given subject subtree, so I get a copy of the subject tree (i.e. the script files), can edit it, and "upload" them upon re-sync. Because: Yes I agree it is a nightmare to mass-edit QC-stored QTP tests, especially with version control enabled.

Comment: Pixie, my scripts were kept in svn so it was easy to recurse through the filesystem.  If I were storing the scripts and libraries in QC I'd do what TheBlastOne suggests.

Answer (score 1):

There is a product called Test Design Studio, an IDE alternative for QuickTest and UFT.  One of the key features it provides is the ability to generate detailed documentation.  It uses XML-style comments to mark up your code, and those comments drive documentation.  The same comments also drive detailed IntelliSense for editing your code.

It does exactly what you're talking about.

[Test Design Studio](http://www.patterson-consulting.net/products/test_design_studio/Default.aspx)

Comment: ok let´s see what the trial version can do...

Comment: first looks... it was done for QTP 11.00 or older and by using UFT 12 now I might lose some features. good idea though...

Comment: Works with UFT 11.5x and UFT 12 as well.  Website just hasn't been updated.  The product primarily hits the code files for each action, and those don't break from one release of QTP/UFT to the next.